# In my text area the scrollbars do not appear to be visible or working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

So I have a simple text editor and at the moment most of its features are working, however adding scroll bars is where i'm having trouble. I tried looking up stuff with adding to the frame and going from there, but that just removes my ability to type or see anything. At the moment I'm adding with the content pane, but it doesn't seem to register the scrollbars. Also when it does there are not usable and the rest of the text area is uneditable.Here is the small bit of code that deals with that, could you help me find what's going wrong.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter.HighlightPainter;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import java.net.URI;

public class MyTextEditor extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(0,0);
private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea, 
              JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
private MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar(); 
private Menu file = new Menu();
private Menu edit = new Menu();
private Menu find = new Menu();
private Menu goTo = new Menu();
private Menu help = new Menu();
private Menu prefs = new Menu();
//File 
private MenuItem openFile = new MenuItem(); 
private MenuItem saveFile = new MenuItem(); 
private MenuItem closeFile = new MenuItem();
private MenuItem newFile = new MenuItem(); 
//Edit
private MenuItem copy = new MenuItem();
private MenuItem paste = new MenuItem();
private MenuItem cut = new MenuItem();
private MenuItem search = new MenuItem();
private MenuItem replace = new MenuItem();
//GoTo
private MenuItem goToLine = new MenuItem();
//Help
private MenuItem documentation = new MenuItem();
//Prefs
private MenuItem toggleLines = new MenuItem();



public MyTextEditor()
{
    //Set the basis for the text editor
    this.setSize(750,800);
    frame.setTitle("Zenith");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    textArea.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 14));
    textArea.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    textArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
  textArea.setCaretColor(Color.WHITE);
    //scrollPane.setBounds(20, 30, 100, 40);
    textArea.getCaret().setVisible(true);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
  scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,50));
  //scrollPane.add(textArea);
  scrollPane.setVisible(true);

    //scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().isVisible();
    //scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().isVisible();

    //textArea.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.EAST);

    // Line numbers
  final LineNumberingTextArea lineNTA = new LineNumberingTextArea(textArea);
  DocumentListener documentListen = new DocumentListener()
  {
     public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent)
     {
        lineNTA.updateLineNumbers();  
     }
     public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent)
     {
        lineNTA.updateLineNumbers();
     }
     public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent)
     {
        lineNTA.updateLineNumbers();
     }
  };
  textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListen); 
    lineNTA.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    lineNTA.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    lineNTA.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 13));
    lineNTA.setEditable(false);
    lineNTA.setVisible(true);

  getContentPane().add(lineNTA,BorderLayout.WEST);
  getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
  getContentPane().add(textArea);
    //getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(lineNTA);
    //frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);
    //panel.add(lineNumber,BorderLayout.EAST);
    //Numbers along the side

    setMenuBar(this.menuBar);
    menuBar.add(this.file);
    menuBar.add(this.edit); 
    menuBar.add(this.find);
  menuBar.add(this.goTo);
  menuBar.add(this.help);
  menuBar.add(this.prefs);

    file.setLabel("File");
    find.setLabel("Find");
    edit.setLabel("Edit");
  goTo.setLabel("Goto");
  help.setLabel("Help");
  prefs.setLabel("Preferences");
```

Comment: Please see edit to answer. Also if this does not answer your question, then please create and post a valid [mcve].

Comment: Please see further edits to answer including code. Again, if stuck create and post your [mcve]. An example of this type of code is posted with my answer.

Comment: Edited a 3rd time. Please comment back if any questions or confusions with my answer.

Comment: ...................hello???

Answer (score 3):

I see several issues with your code, but the main one being that you appear to be trying to add the JTextArea to the GUI two or maybe even three times:

You first add it to the JScrollPane:

```
private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea, 
          JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

And add that JScrollPane to the GUI

```
getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```

But then immediately after, you appear to add just the JTextArea ***without*** its JScrollPane to the GUI:

```
getContentPane().add(textArea);
```

Understand that you can add a component to the GUI only once. If you try to add it a 2nd time, it is removed from the prior container, leaving it empty. Not only that, by adding a component to a BorderLayout-using container in this way (the content pane), you replace the JScrollPane from the GUI completely.

You also might be adding the JTextArea to the GUI a **third** time when you add it to your LineNumberingTextArea constructor:

```
final LineNumberingTextArea lineNTA = new LineNumberingTextArea(textArea);
```

and then add the LineNumberingTextArea object to the GUI:

```
getContentPane().add(lineNTA,BorderLayout.WEST);
```

We don't know what goes on inside of your LineNumberingTextArea, but if you're adding the JTextArea to the LineNumberingTextArea instance, and then as above are adding your LineNumberingTextArea instance to the GUI, again that makes three times that you're trying to add the JTextArea to a container, which is two times too many.

Again, you can only add a component to the GUI once.

Other side issues:

- You are trying to set the sizes or preferred sizes of components, something you will want to avoid. Rather let the components and the layout managers size themselves to their best sizes.
- You're setting your JTextArea rows and columns properties to too small values of 0,0: `private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(0,0);`. Much better to use this constructor as a more robust way of having the JTextArea size itself appropriately by passing in more reasonable values.
- You're also adding components to a BorderLayout-using container, the contentPane, in a default way, multiple times, which means that you're displacing any component added previously with the newly added components, something that is likely further confusing you.
- You're creating two JFrames -- why? One is the when you create an instance of MyTextEditor, since it extends from JFrame. This is the JFrame that gets all components. The other is a private field:

```
private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

and you call methods on it:

```
frame.setTitle("Zenith");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

but never add anything to it or display it. Since this will serve no purpose other than to confuse, you should get rid of one JFrame or the other. Again this suggests that you might want to start over and start cleaner and with a well-defined purpose.

---

---

For example, a simple GUI demo:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleScrollPaneGui extends JPanel {
    private static final int ROWS = 25;
    private static final int COLUMNS = 60;
    private static final Color TA_BACKGRND = Color.BLACK;
    private static final Color TA_FOREGRND = Color.GREEN;
    private static final Color TA_CARET_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    private static final Font TA_FONT = new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 14);

    // first off size your JTextArea by setting visible rows and columns
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLUMNS); 

    public SimpleScrollPaneGui() {
        // set the text area properties
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setBackground(TA_BACKGRND);
        textArea.setForeground(TA_FOREGRND);
        textArea.setCaretColor(TA_CARET_COLOR);
        textArea.setFont(TA_FONT);

        // create jscrollpane, passing in jtextarea into its viewport:
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // add **just the jscrollpane to the GUI
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SimpleScrollPaneGui mainPanel = new SimpleScrollPaneGui();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple ScrollPane GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```